# GLFW camera input C++

Tags: c++, glfw

I am having a little trouble getting the OpenGL camera to do what I want. When I want it to stop, it will slow down other than stop immediately.
For moving forward slowly,

```
if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
position += speed * orientation;
```

But I have no idea for making it stop slowly other than stop immediately.
Thank you for your answer in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can make keys to influence acceleration instead of speed. When the key is pressed the camera is accelerating, when it is not pressed the camera is decelerating, something like this:

```
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS) {
    speed += acceleration;
} else {
    speed -= acceleration;
}
```

You'll need to clip the speed to certain values:

```
if (speed < 0.0) {
  speed = 0.0;
} else if (speed > MAX_SPEED) {
  speed = MAX_SPEED;
}
```

and then you'll update the position on each tick using the current speed:

```
position += speed * orientation;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! But I have a small question here, when I released the key, it does not jump to the else statement.